# CentOS7 Apache: RSA certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: centos, ssl, apache-virtualhost

I know this issue has been raised before, and I have searched through all the answers and tried all of the suggestions, none of which solved my problem, so I'll ask for assistance in a new thread.

I have installed and configured a new CentOS7 system, to replace one that got too outdated. It primarily exists to serve up a copy of ownCloud on my network. The previous system worked perfectly, and was configured with an SSL certificate. I have copied over the vhosts.conf file, the certificate files, the key file, and set up ownCloud in the same configuration as I had on the previous system.

However, when I start up Apache, it fails and logs these errors:

```
[ssl:info] [pid 4787] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'owncloud.domain.com:443'
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[ssl:info] [pid 4787] AH01914: Configuring server owncloud.domain.com:443 for SSL protocol
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_engine_init.c(1536): AH02209: CA certificate: CN=AddTrust External CA Root,OU=AddTrust External TTP Network,O=AddTrust AB,C=SE
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_engine_init.c(1536): AH02209: CA certificate: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_engine_init.c(1536): AH02209: CA certificate: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_engine_init.c(406): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_engine_init.c(919): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[ssl:warn] [pid 4787] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_util_ssl.c(489): AH02412: [owncloud.domain.com:443] Cert does not match for name 'owncloud.domain.com' [subject: emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=-- / issuer: emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=-- / serial: 7B1C / notbefore: Jul  4 10:13:52 2014 GMT / notafter: Jul  4 10:13:52 2015 GMT]
[ssl:warn] [pid 4787] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for owncloud.domain.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_engine_init.c(974): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
[ssl:emerg] [pid 4787] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[ssl:emerg] [pid 4787] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

The certificate in question is not self-generated -- it is a purchased commercial certificate and was working perfectly on the previous system. Both systems used the same server name, the same IP address and the same vhosts.conf.

The httpd.conf specifies that Apache should listen on both ports 80 and 443.

The vhosts.conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/owncloud
    ServerName owncloud.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.owncloud.domain.com
    Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
    ErrorLog logs/owncloud.domain.com-ssl-error_log
    CustomLog logs/owncloud.domain.com-ssl-access_log common
    <Directory /var/www/html/owncloud >
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv3 +TLSv1
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/pki/tls/certs/owncloud_domain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/owncloud.key
    SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/pki/tls/certs/owncloud_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName owncloud.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://owncloud.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The relevant lines from httpd.conf are:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
ServerName owncloud.domain.com:443
```

The rest of the httpd.conf file is pretty much as it was installed by CentOS.

I have used openSSL to test the certificate and key files, using the -modulus argument, and the results from both are identical. I also tested for the text of the server name and it is correct in the certificate file, so it does not appear as if anything has happened to either the certificate or the key. Nothing should have -- I copied all the certificate files to a backup before installing the new system, then put them back.

As I mentioned, I've tried everything I could find via on-line searching, but nothing has worked, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

-- Norm

As requested, here is the output of "openssl x509 -in owncloud_domain_com.crt -text -noout":

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            7c:a7:38:a8:1a:67:2d:e3:b4:13:fa:49:33:e8:27:e6
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 12 00:00:00 2013 GMT
            Not After : Sep 11 23:59:59 2018 GMT
        Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, OU=PositiveSSL, CN=owncloud.domain.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ca:c8:8d:41:91:c5:0e:ed:86:a4:6a:6f:fb:86:
                    6c:a5:4d:68:cb:80:51:f3:2e:7f:9c:97:8a:43:a0:
                    3e:45:7a:cd:83:ad:a6:72:03:98:20:e5:a0:04:a8:
                    0b:d0:45:e6:62:ec:1d:c0:d7:fa:04:13:30:b5:e8:
                    40:f7:00:ef:14:19:c2:37:f3:dd:af:87:cc:70:d5:
                    dd:51:7a:10:17:35:79:5b:0f:86:4e:d8:ce:73:11:
                    96:d4:00:c8:41:f9:7d:5c:2e:c5:06:6b:4d:04:d6:
                    11:6a:03:80:11:c5:06:d9:f5:d1:6d:60:2b:a8:3b:
                    ba:5d:38:0b:1d:dc:dc:48:3d:ae:ef:7b:48:c2:d9:
                    5c:c2:72:83:46:bc:d2:78:fd:02:cf:a8:b3:99:66:
                    36:05:9b:89:56:26:96:2c:1c:eb:54:6d:31:39:32:
                    4d:e9:f0:b9:b1:ca:e3:8d:40:85:03:9a:37:2d:94:
                    e8:a6:2c:c9:fd:ba:d2:8f:5c:95:63:e4:52:55:f8:
                    4a:5a:14:af:a1:ba:38:4d:b8:d9:92:28:98:3d:40:
                    89:e3:43:f1:bc:ea:14:29:3e:40:09:ad:f8:35:29:
                    80:1b:4d:a4:91:e2:9d:0b:0c:e5:0d:2b:13:a5:07:
                    82:9a:97:6b:6f:b1:69:c5:4d:c1:1b:11:cd:07:2c:
                    38:eb:e7:bb:93:2f:57:aa:a1:38:bb:b7:70:5c:89:
                    6d:47:d8:e0:6d:1b:9e:60:50:83:b6:93:49:36:7e:
                    57:c8:c8:2a:f7:30:cb:ee:a5:f5:e7:0c:f3:6f:1a:
                    82:54:a2:20:49:f5:68:c4:f1:c2:7b:0e:29:28:a8:
                    2c:9c:52:f4:5f:39:25:2f:fe:f4:ea:7e:92:cc:95:
                    c9:a5:92:2a:06:8e:9c:00:d0:c1:1c:52:e0:fb:42:
                    1b:fe:8c:ef:49:82:9a:55:74:5b:95:e1:ec:a6:6f:
                    96:e6:ae:0d:d9:be:24:db:4e:cc:e0:2d:a3:61:cb:
                    2a:e3:67:81:6f:5a:72:80:7c:0f:1b:e0:8b:ad:9e:
                    e2:6a:f7:32:0b:78:c1:ca:ac:38:97:7a:76:53:0f:
                    9d:12:49:5b:ab:d9:ea:b9:ca:cb:8d:e1:fa:bd:f8:
                    11:05:05:c7:90:f0:4e:f3:81:75:57:4a:3e:2a:3a:
                    10:65:34:ea:1c:c0:18:68:bb:f9:0a:6e:ee:fe:73:
                    16:6d:1f:e8:2c:bf:91:3d:df:26:98:93:8d:88:52:
                    04:7d:46:ab:eb:6f:e0:9f:1d:f9:ed:b2:75:dc:d8:
                    eb:61:69:14:83:12:82:09:75:c5:5a:51:a4:2d:17:
                    fa:ce:66:16:11:bd:5a:a8:ea:9e:af:b3:06:03:86:
                    5e:fb:6d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:90:AF:6A:3A:94:5A:0B:D8:90:EA:12:56:73:DF:43:B4:3A:28:DA:E7

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                8C:70:79:27:C0:EE:36:6F:23:58:2E:46:2B:A6:A7:DE:E3:39:99:B1
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.1.3.4
                  CPS: https://secure.comodo.net/CPS
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.comodoca.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crl

            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://crt.comodoca.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.comodoca.com

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:owncloud.domain.com, DNS:www.owncloud.domain.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         3a:a6:56:b7:56:ce:f0:ed:e6:ba:d7:1c:31:9d:ff:3d:67:88:
         f3:6c:d8:c9:28:42:06:b7:66:2b:39:c6:0b:c4:0a:b2:1d:5e:
         f6:4f:4b:30:65:1c:71:4e:a8:89:03:2a:28:45:ca:10:f6:dd:
         34:7e:1a:e2:51:a5:c6:32:46:b5:7d:6d:da:2e:ef:51:73:0d:
         11:f4:eb:2d:82:4f:22:82:50:fc:ad:be:45:f3:32:96:eb:11:
         88:6b:a6:62:3d:3f:7b:a9:b5:d8:af:a4:40:03:00:05:cf:fa:
         6b:6a:41:d1:7c:26:6e:66:b0:5a:36:9c:d2:b5:c4:c7:a2:c2:
         ce:3a:27:6a:e9:35:18:54:0d:52:05:30:fc:57:74:68:43:ea:
         9b:bb:39:d8:b2:81:e8:8a:b6:f2:31:36:81:f4:b7:16:16:1c:
         ff:e5:e2:d5:23:78:e2:13:26:8e:31:1e:e1:9f:fd:d2:b7:20:
         d4:75:a4:74:32:c3:e9:25:b7:d5:1d:ab:e8:d6:ea:80:13:58:
         77:e1:f5:d7:dd:b0:3d:ca:bc:4c:24:40:ff:2d:d2:15:12:97:
         56:ed:04:87:aa:85:98:89:b4:f3:ce:32:67:de:43:80:36:fd:
         b5:32:2a:69:fb:4d:65:f8:fb:be:fa:08:d1:3b:a6:12:28:46:
         34:31:24:1a
```

Replacing `SSLCACertificateFile` with `SSLCertificateChainFile` in the vhosts file, and starting Apache gives these log messages:

```
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.296052 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 6048] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'owncloud.domain.com:443'
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.296536 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 6048] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.296856 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 6048] AH01914: Configuring server owncloud.domain.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297384 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 6048] ssl_engine_init.c(872): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (3 CA certificates)
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297399 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 6048] ssl_engine_init.c(406): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297413 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 6048] ssl_engine_init.c(919): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297509 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 6048] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297599 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 6048] ssl_util_ssl.c(489): AH02412: [owncloud.domain.com:443] Cert does not match for name 'owncloud.domain.com' [subject: emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=-- / issuer: emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=-- / serial: 7B1C / notbefore: Jul  4 10:13:52 2014 GMT / notafter: Jul  4 10:13:52 2015 GMT]
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297612 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 6048] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for owncloud.domain.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297621 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 6048] ssl_engine_init.c(974): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297649 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 6048] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Thu May 03 17:39:52.297667 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 6048] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

In effect, not much has changed, as Apache still won't start.

As requested, the first few lines of the private key file:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEwAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKowggSmAgEAAoIBAQDCcib4fqnUYaGV
mzy6h6e6EUonHY+WeqkwygWV/zwZEcto9pKMyv5ZSYRPTsW4/e3glPMXBlbxIzhj
6f1W76AP8nYplcWJLuj/Qn+JHfaA7nlCHUehtA2Vcut9AuVnvutZZyA3fp+EySXv
Mu8/RhKjXx0C8Zm6vvGKJczw4MSP8JlUtYs+KoXXzVsTbrLCgLBYf0+JUoKBU9s4
Um37cMk8ziRKYZDjsYtKe1D7hA6A3sWZp7czidK7jGH2OoWVHrj46pTo/koxhJpV
```

Comment: Nope, no chroot. It's all pretty plain vanilla.

Comment: Can you replace  `SSLCACertificateFile` by  `SSLCertificateChainFile` and (re)start Apache?

Comment: results added to the main question

Comment: As I mentioned, this all worked perfectly on the previous incarnation of this server, which is one of the reasons why I'm stumped.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there should be no ServerName in httpd.conf *and*  SSLCertificateChainFile should be used for the bundle file.

Comment: Well, the comments in the httpd.conf file specifically say that there should be a ServerName, but taking it out didn't make any difference.

Comment: I've requested a refresh of the certificate. It will likely take a day or so to go through the process, but I'll see if it makes any difference. Thanks for your help to this point.

Comment: The cert is sha256... see this too https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064

Comment: I had originally compared the modulus values of the certificate and key to verify that they belonged together. The link you provided has a few neat tricks for doing this.
However, it didn't find anything. I got the newly provided certificate and bundle file and inserted them into the system. I modified vhosts to point to them, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Your private key has been on the back of my head. Can you show us the header (first 3 lines, I think)?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean -- do you want the first lines after "--BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--" in the .key file, or something extracted via openssl? I'm happy to oblige but just not sure what you want.

Comment: Yes, the first lines please

Comment: added them to the end of the main message

Comment: Key seems to have the right header and in a recent format. Officially out of ideas.

Comment: First off, I wonder how many bits of the private key you exposed... Not entirely sure (would have to look up the format of that file). Also, every error message you're getting is pretty clearly saying you've got another `SSLCertificateFile` *somewhere* which is pointing to your CA's certificate, not yours.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21102/what-is-the-ssl-private-key-file-format seems to say the modulus comes first, followed by the public exponent (i.e., a copy of the public key)... So that should be fine, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `openssl x509 -in owncloud_domain_com.crt -text -noout` output says that the certificate is not a CA certificate and that it should be valid from September 2013 to September 2018.

However, Apache's messages seem to talk about some other certificate:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 4787] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

...and here (line wrapped for readability):

```
[ssl:debug] [pid 4787] ssl_util_ssl.c(489): AH02412: [owncloud.domain.com:443]
Cert does not match for name 'owncloud.domain.com' 
[subject: emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,
OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=-- / 
issuer: emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,
OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=-- /
serial: 7B1C / notbefore: Jul  4 10:13:52 2014 GMT / notafter: Jul  4 10:13:52 2015 GMT]
```

The certificate Apache is reading has a Common Name of "localhost.localdomain" and it has been expired since July 2015.

This really looks like a default auto-generated "snakeoil" certificate, rather than the certificate you're talking about.

Please run `grep -r SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd` and see if remnants of the default configuration are left in any other Apache configuration file. It might be that another `SSLCertificateFile` directive is overriding the one you've specified in your `vhosts.conf`.

Comment: SUCCESS! It turns out that there was an SSLCertificateFile line in the default ssl.conf file that was indeed pointing to the localhost.crt file. This must have been put in place when I installed mod_ssl via yum. I know I looked at the ssl.conf content several times, but must have thought the SSLCertificateFile line would be superseded by my vhosts file. Stupid of me, but Linux isn't my long suit. Thanks very much to everyone who contributed to this frustrating issue.

Cheers
Norm

Answer (score 1):

I've run into same issue and was able to track the cause, thanks to telcoM's answer, only with one additional twist - so I'm writing this as a reference for others that might have the same problem.

I'm mixing several commercial certificates with Let's Encrypt ones on my server and indeed the defaul ssl.conf file had been also loading the commercial ones, therefore making mess of my Let's Encrypt setup. So I've commented it out and moved the lines somewhere up in my httpd.conf. Anyway still no luck - the sites using the commercial certificates were all right but the let's encrypt one still didn't work. So I've looked into the httpd error logs and interestingly enough, in my ssl_error_log there was also a message saying that the `configured RSA certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name` speaking about the domain itself but when I examined the httpd error log for that specific domain the error was a little bit different and was speaking about localhost. So I figured - maybe there's a problem with /etc/hosts. And it really was!

My /etc/hosts have had a row pointing the domain name to 127.0.0.1. Under that there was a line using the real IP address (so the http version of that web was working fine all the time). I just removed the line with 127.0.0.1, restarted the server and everything works like a charm!

Comment: Update: there was an additional layer of problem - since I've been using multiple versions of PHP in FPM mode, some of the configs were shadowing other ones - I thought there are no errors generated but instead they have been flooding my other partition. So this huge error log ate up all of my space where the sessions should also be stored... so yes, in the end it was a dumb problem not having enough space.